# Границы Excel в PHP

Tags: php, excel, border

Не могу задать черную границу ячейки

```
$sheet->getStyle('B3')
  ->getBorders()
  ->getLeft()
  ->applyFromArray(array(
    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
    'color' => array('rgb'=>'000000')));
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблема так:

```
$sheet->getStyle('B3')->applyFromArray(
    array('fill'    => array(
        'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'color'     => array('rgb' => 'FFFFFF')
    ),
        'borders' => array(
            'bottom'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK),
            'right'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK),
            'top'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK),
            'left'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK)

        )
    ));
```